# Obtain Confirm Answer upon submission

Tags: c#, confirm

In my C# code, I have presented a confirm box to the user using the following code:

```
string confirmMsg = "All the cause data will be permanently removed. Are you sure you want    to continue";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "TWCL Issue Mgmt System", "confirm('" + confirmMsg + "');", true);
```

I am trying to get the answer (YES or No) into a boolean or some other variable so that I can execute other code based on the answer given. So I would like something like this:

```
bool x = ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "TWCL Issue Mgmt System", "confirm('" + confirmMsg + "');", true);
if(x)
{
 /*Exceute the rest of the code here*/
}
else
{
  /*do postback*/
}
```

Any ideas on how to get the YES/NO answer from the confirm box?

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden field on the form. Write the answer of the question in the hidden field with some javascript. Read the value of the hidden field in the code behind.

Comment: I tried this method by first adding a hidden field called "hdnConfirm". I tried this method with this code (to no avail):

string confirmMsg = "All the cause data will be permanently removed. Are you sure you want to continue";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "TWCL Issue Mgmt System", "document.getElementById('MainContent_hdnConfirm').Value = confirm('" + confirmMsg + "');", true);

Can you show me a sample code of what you are saying?

Answer (score 0):

The startup script that you are registering will run when the web page is displayed, before the user has had a chance to interact with it.  A confirmation prompt at this time will likely be confusing.

It's more usual to use the `OnClientClick` property of a button that is doing the postback:

```
<asp:Button ...
   OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" 
/>
```

so that the confirmation prompt is only displayed when the user attempts to post.

Comment: That was the code I had before. But the user wants something else. The confirmation happens when a drop down list changes. However, I changed it so that when the selected index has changed, then it checks to see if a value is already assigned to a particular field in the DB. If the value is null, then I don't want to show the confirm box, I just want to populate some fields. If the value is not empty and the user wants to change it anyways, then I show the confirm box. So that's why I have to resort to putting it in the c# code rather than the .aspx code